# How to do inheritance with JavaScript object literals?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

Hello I have a problem with how to do inheritance while declaring object prototypes with object literal syntax.

I have made two Fiddles to help you help me.

- [Fiddle1, This one works](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSqQW/)
- [Fiddle2, This one doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/DnrU9/3/)

This is my base class, almost all objects is defined in this way in my application:

```
Base = function(param){
    this.init(param);
}
Base.prototype = {
    init: function(param){
        this.param = param;
    },
    calc: function(){
        var result = this.param * 10;
        document.write("Result from calc in Base: " + result + "<br/>");
    },
    calcB: function(){
        var result = this.param * 20;
        document.write("Result from calcB in Base: " + result+ "<br/>");
    }
}
```

This is how I succeed extending and overriding methods in Base:

```
Extend = function(param){
    this.init(param);
}
Extend.prototype = new Base();

Extend.prototype.calc = function(){
    var result = this.param * 50;
    document.write("Result from calc in Extend: " + result+ "<br/>");
}
```

But I wanted to use the same style as the rest of the application so I started playing around with object literals but it is driving me nuts eagerly cheered on by eclipse and firebug with its nonsense response to my syntax.

Now on to the question of how do I convert my succeeded extension code to object literal style?
Here is one of many attempts (it don't compile but will give you an rough idea how I want the code to look like.)

```
Extend = function(param){
    this.init(param);
}
Extend.prototype = {
    : new Base(),
    calc: function(){
        var result = this.param * 50;
        document.write("Result from calc in Extend: " + result+ "<br/>");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are attempting. JSON is a text data format and has nothing to do with object inheritance. Do you maybe mean JavaScript literal object notation?

Comment: It may very well be what I mean, the correct terminology of JavaScript is not my strong suit. It's also why I didn't say JSON but JSON style.

Comment: @Farmor "I want to program by using object literals".

Comment: I've made some minor edits to the question to change the terminology to "object literals". Or should that have been "objects literal"? I think from now on "objects literal" it shall be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want [`Object.make`](https://github.com/Raynos/pd#pd.make). [Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/DnrU9/6/)

```
Extend = function(param){
    this.init(param);
}
Extend.prototype = Object.make(Base.prototype, {
    constructor: Extend,
    calc: function(){
        var result = this.param * 50;
        document.write("Result from calc in Extend: " + result+ "<br/>");
    }
});
```

If you want an ES5 compliant implementation of `Object.make` to just plug into your code then use

```
Object.make = function make (proto) {
    var o = Object.create(proto);
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    args.forEach(function (obj) {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(function (key) {
            o[key] = obj[key];
        });
    });
    return o;
}
```

Comment: During testing I found out that IE8 doesn't support ES5/Object.create this could easy be verified by opening your fiddle in IE8. I am working on the problem and will post back with an solution.

Comment: @Farmor [Use the ES5-shim for legacy platform support](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the original prototype rather than assigning a new object as the prototype.

```
function extend(original, extension) {
  for (var key in extension) {
    if (extension.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      original[key] = extension[key];
    }
  }
};

var A = function () {};
var B = function () {};
B.prototype = new A();
extend(B.prototype, {
   methodName: function () {}
});
```